# PHP open database connection

Tags: php, mysql

I just wanna ask for your help guys. Im having a problem with my coding which is to open database connection.  Here is my code.

```
<?php

define('MYHOST', 'localhost');
define('MYDATABASE', 'system');
define('MYUSERNAME', 'root');
define('MYPASSWORD', 'root');


$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "")

if ($mydb->connect_error) {

  die("Connection Error Message: ".$mydb->connect_error);
 }

?>
```

and it show an error like this

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database.php on line 11

thank you guys for your answer..

Comment: Add a semi colon at the end of the line $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "");

Comment: missing `;` at the end of `$conn` line

Comment: also you're killing kittens using a deprecated library. use `mysqli_` or PDO

Comment: This extension (mysql_) was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, Please use mysql or PDO instead

Answer (score 1):

This extension (mysql_) was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, please use mysqli or PDO(PHP Data Objects) instead.

If your PHP versional lower than 5.5.0, you can edit this line:

```
$conn = mysql_connect(MYHOST, MYDATABASE, MYUSERNAME, MYPASSWORD);
```

to replace this:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in the your code:

- You are missing the semicolon(;) in the line number 11  .
- You are using the invalid variable for the connection($mydb), replace it with ($conn).

Try the below script, hope this helps:

```
<?php

    define('MYHOST', 'localhost');
    define('MYDATABASE', 'system');
    define('MYUSERNAME', 'root');
    define('MYPASSWORD', 'root');


    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "");

    if ($conn->connect_error) {

      die("Connection Error Message: ".$conn->connect_error);
     }

    ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using the values instead of the constants in the connection string?